# system password vs administrator password in BIOS settings

Tags: bios, passwords

I just received a new Dell laptop. In the BIOS menus, I'm able to set a "system password" but unable to set an "administrator password" (greyed out).
What is the distinction between these two passwords in the BIOS.

Comment: post the exact model of Dell, maybe we can find documentation on the Dell site.

Comment: The model is Dell 3147.

Comment: Check the edit to my answer

Comment: related: [administrator vs user password](https://superuser.com/questions/1164035/)

Answer (score 5):

1.System Password: This will be prompted before the system can boot up, and load the operating system.

2.Setup password: The system will prompt for this password only when you are trying to access the BIOS settings.

[Source](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/05/dell-bios-password/)

[Here are your manuals for the Dell Inspiron 11 (3147)](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-11-3147-laptop/manuals)